# Connect sql server 2005 using PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to connect SQL Server 2005 using PHP. I searched in Google but am not getting proper solution, it's showing search results about `mssql_connect()` is not working properly. By seeing this am not getting anything.

```
      require_once 'login.php';
     $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
     mysql_select_db($db_database) or die("Unable to connect to database: ".mysql_error());
```

This will connect mysql database. I tried replace `mysql_connect()` with `mssql_connect()`. But its not working. `login.php` has

```
  $db_hostname = 'localhost';
  $db_database = 'urlstore';
  $db_username = 'root';
  $db_password = 'tiger';
```

How can I connect SQL database using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install MS SQL PHP extensions and then you can work with your MS SQL Server the way you are used to.

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) is the information about the extension and how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PDO if your server configuration supports it. PDO is an abstraction layer that allows you to connect to many different database types using the same object.

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO ('mssql:host='.$mssql_server.';dbname='.$mssql_db, $mssql_login, $mssql_pwd);
    $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO tablename(column1, column2) VALUES ('stuff', 'here')");
    $dbh = null;
    }
catch (PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

This code can help you determine if PDO is enabled:

```
<?php
    foreach(PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $driver)
    {
        echo $driver.'<br />';
    }
?>
```

OR you can run this:

```
<?php phpInfo(); ?>
```

and look for this:

> **PDO**
>
> **PDO support**  PDO drivers
>
> **enabled** dblib, mysql, odbc, pgsql, sqlite, sqlite2

If it isn't enabled for MSSQL, you can uncomment the "extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll" line in php.ini.

If it still doesn't work, you might want to try this:

> ntwdblib.dll - The most common issue is that you do not have the
>   ntwdblib.dll file installed in your PHP directory (where php.exe is,
>   or sometimes placing it in the ext directory works as well). This
>   library can be found with your Enterprise Manager dll's or in your SQL
>   servers system32 folder. It's generally best to take the file from the
>   server where SQL Server is installed
>   -quoted from http://www.helpspot.com/helpdesk/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=13